# XPath to select all elements with a specified name

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I believe this should be able to be answered just using standard XPath without reference to implementation, but just for reference I am using the XML DOM objects in .Net (System.Xml namespace).

I have a node handed to my function, from somewhere deep inside an XML document, and I want to select all descendant elements of this node that have a specific name, regardless of the intervening path to those nodes.  The call I'm making looks like this:

```
node.SelectNodes("some XPath here");
```

The node I'm working with looks something like this:

```
...
<food>
  <tart>
    <apple color="yellow"/>
  </tart>
  <pie>
    <crust quality="flaky"/>
    <filling>
      <apple color="red"/>
    </filling>
  </pie>
  <apple color="green"/>
</food>
...
```

What I want is a list of all of the "apple" nodes, i.e. 3 results.
I've tried a couple of different things, but none of them get what I want.

```
node.SelectNodes("apple");
```

This gives me one result, the green apple.

```
node.SelectNodes("*/apple");
```

This gives me one result, the yellow apple.

```
node.SelectNodes("//apple");
```

This gives me hundreds of results, looks like every apple node in the document, or at least maybe every apple node that is a direct child of the root of the document.

How do I create an XPath that will give me all the apple nodes under my current node, regardless of how deep under the current node they are found?  Specifically, based on my example above, I should get three results - the red, green, and yellow apples.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try `.//apple`. This lists all the `apple` nodes that are descendants of the current node. For a better understanding of this topic, you should learn how XPath axes work. You could also write `descendant::apple`, for example.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I Googled for an hour and couldn't find that.  Just to clarify, to see that I understand the syntax correctly - the double slashes give me all the apple nodes regardless of depth (as I tried in my question above), and the dot before them limits the selection to descendants of the current node.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I also edited my post to give you some additional pointers.

Comment: You edited your answer to say I should learn how XPath axes work - I agree.  Do you have any suggestions of good resources I should check out?

Comment: @SeanWorle and others: MDN has a great [XPath Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath). The first topic on that page is about [axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes).