# XML starlet to select all nodes with name X

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

What XPath expression is needed to use xml starlet select command to get all the XML nodes in the file with name X?

EDIT:

Using this xml

```
<Parent>
    <Children>

        <Child>
            <Size width="100" height="100"/>
        </Child>

        <Child>
            <Size width="200" height="200"/>
        </Child>

    </Children>
</Parent>
```

When I run this command nothing is output to the console. I am running version 1.6.1

C:[path_to_xml]>xml sel -t -v "//Size" test.xml

C:[path_to_xml]>

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077462/xpath-to-select-all-elements-with-a-specified-name it is implied that `node.SelectNodes("//X");` would work but I don't know how to feed something like that to startlet.

Answer (score 0):

This xmlstarlet command,

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Size" -v "@width" test.xml
```

will select all `Size` elements in test.xml and return their `width` attributes.

Note that earlier versions of xmlstarlet (eg v1.0.1) had issues with returning multiple values.  See [xmlstarlet XPath expression selects single result rather than multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079965/xmlstarlet-xpath-expression-selects-single-result-rather-than-multiple).

Comment: That just outputs like 20 blank lines to the console on my windows system.

Comment: Add a [mcve] to your question that includes a minimal XML file and the version of xmlstarlet you're using.  Thanks.

Comment: @Scorb:  I just noticed that you updated your question to show the issue you mentioned in your follow-up comment.  I believe it's fixed now.  Sorry for the four-year delay.  :-)